# Create a record with Flow, with a Lookup to link an Account to my custom object

Tags: visual-workflow, custom-object, lookup

I'm trying to Create a record with Flow, with a Lookup to link an Account to my custom object Projet.

In my custom object Projet. The field Compte is a lookup to Account.

[image]

Now i could not figure how to fill it to make it work in Flow/Screen/Lookup.

[image]

Any advise ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you using Lightning page to setup the Lookup for "Compte" field? Please check the FLS for the field. Whether the user have access to this field.  Pretty much an odd issue never come across something like this.

Comment: Ok i have find what i need in this Doc from Salesforce. https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_ref_elements_screencmp_lookup.htm&type=5

Comment: Can you post an answer with the detail? It's perfectly acceptable to answer your own question and mark that as the accepted answer.